# Showing Review Summary on Cart Page

Tags: cart, review

I'm trying to show review summary on cart page.

I've tried adding these lines in template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml page

```
  $_item = $this->getItem();

 <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, "short", true)?>
```

But it didn't work. Searched the internet but didn't find any solution.

I know it is a simple task, but i'm stuck on it. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem here us because reviews are attached to the product and not the cart item. To add the review to the cart you need the product and not the cart item. If you update your code as follows:

```
$reviewHelper = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/helper');
echo $reviewHelper->getSummaryHtml($_item->getProduct(), 'short', true);
```

Then it should display the summary. Basically you need to load the product from the cart item and then pass this to the review helper function.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me in 1.9.2.1. I am no coding expert. Someone may have a better way to tweak this, but this is what I found through trial and error mixed with what I've found in other threads too.

I added the following to the existing php at the beginning of the file

> /app/design/frontend/yourcustomtheme/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

```
$_product= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProductId());
```

Be sure it appears within php tags.

I then used the same coding provided by waldek_c, but used $_product instead of $_item.

```
<?php $reviewHelper = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/helper');
echo $reviewHelper->getSummaryHtml($_product, 'short', true);?>
```

I get both the short review and "Be the first to review this product." If you ONLY want to show the review when a product has a review and remove the "Be the first to review this product" message, remove ", true" from the code.

So, only use:

```
<?php $reviewHelper = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/helper');
echo $reviewHelper->getSummaryHtml($_product, 'short');?>
```

To show Order Review Summary in your Sales Order page, you can also use this in

> /app/design/frontend/yourcustomtheme/template/sales/order/items/renderer/default.phtml

to encourage your customer to leave a review by changing `($_product, 'short', true)` to `($_product, false, true)`. This will display the number of reviews (3 customer reviews | Add your review) with the "Add your review" link.

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

try this way:

```
<?php
$reviewHelper = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('review/helper');
echo $reviewHelper->getSummaryHtml($_item, 'short', true);
```

Comment: It started showing 'No one review was added' even when the product has active reviews added to it. So, I think we are close, but not right there.

Comment: Check in admin if the review is Accepted, `Catalog->Reviews And Ratings->CustomerReviews->PendingRevies` set status on Approved

Comment: Yes they are. The reviews are even showing on product detail page. But still on cart page for the same product it shows 'No one review was added'